# get zend FlashMessenger message as string

Tags: php, zend-framework, zend-framework3

I have following code in controller as below:

```
public function indexAction(){
   $this->flashMessenger()->addMessage('hi');
}
```

In view page :

```
$messages = $this->flashMessenger()->getMessages();
            foreach($messages as $message) {
                echo $message.' ';
            }
```

as above code is working, but `flashmessenger` returns `array`.
I want something that could return `strings` only.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`var_dump($message)` to see what's in the array.

Then `echo $message['keyYouNeedHere'];` to get it to output, obviously replacing `keyYouNeedHere` with the actual array key index.

Also, read up the documentation here https://framework.zend.com/manual/2.3/en/modules/zend.view.helpers.flash-messenger.html

Without your loop, you can use the helper like so:

`echo $this->flashMessenger()->render();`

You can also edit the HTML markup that gets generated to suit. Look into it!